# How to read each log file with different thread

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, remote-server, threadpoolexecutor

Basically, I'm connecting to remote server and getting all the log file names from the log folder. I'm adding those file name in list and Now I want to read or tail -f on that file and I should seek if any file encounter "Error" then I should be able to write that other file.
I want to use Multi threading and I want to create threads to read each log file individually.

For Example:

```
public List<String> excuteScript(String fileName) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        JSch jSch = new JSch();
        Session session = jSch.getSession(USERNAME, host, port);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setPassword(PASSWORD);
        session.connect();
        //create the excution channel over the session
        ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");

        // Gets an InputStream for this channel. All data arriving in as messages from the remote side can be read from this stream.
        InputStream in = channelExec.getInputStream();

        // Set the command that you want to execute
        // In our case its the remote shell script
        channelExec.setCommand("sh " + fileName);

        // Execute the command
        channelExec.connect();
        System.out.println("connected");

        // Read the output from the input stream we set above
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line;

        //Read each line from the buffered reader and add it to result list
        // You can also simple print the result here 
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.contains("Error") || line.contains("Exception")) {
                System.out.println(line);
                result.add(line);
            }
        }
        //retrieve the exit status of the remote command corresponding to this channel
        int exitStatus = channelExec.getExitStatus();

        //Safely disconnect channel and disconnect session. If not done then it may cause resource leak
        channelExec.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();

        if(exitStatus < 0) {
            // System.out.println("Done, but exit status not set!");
        }
        else if(exitStatus > 0) {
            // System.out.println("Done, but with error!");
        }
        else {
            // System.out.println("Done!");
        }
    } 
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you say or [tag]  the programming language you are using.

Comment: It would help if you say or [tag] that you're using `com.jcraft.jsch.JSch` - http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Comment: I do not get it. Where are those multiple files that you want to process?